# problem with newly installed pip (or maybe with python 3.7 as well)

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

I got confused with how to source activate the correct venv.

I used to use pip v10. I have a working venv called "base_py36" and I could `source activate base_py36` with everything OK.

Recently I upgraded pip to pip v19. Now when I run `source activate base_py36`, it goes into the venv but all my installed packages are gone.

PS: when I searched the venv directory, I found that under /anaconda3/envs/base_py36/lib I have both python3.6 and python3.7 with different packages. So could this be the reason? (I cannot remember when I installed python 3.7). If so how could I `source activate base_py36` with python 3.6?

Comment: Hello, can you elaborate on how you upgraded pip ? What steps did you take ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you mean "with python 3.7" at the end.

But yes, that is the most likely cuplrit. For a quick, albeit lazy, workaround, you can just copy the modules from Python 3.6 to Python 3.7. Since there is so little difference between the two, they're guaranteed to be forward compatible, at least for now.

Also, if that doesn't work, could you activate the virtual environment, and tell us what version of python it's running?

Comment: So I tried your method to copy over python3.6 and rename it as python3.7. When I run "jupyter notebook", I got this error message:  Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
Current thread 0x00007fff8d6cf380 (most recent call first):
Abort trap: 6